# ClassNotFoundException: ddf.minim.Minim

Tags: processing, minim

I came across this error for few hours.
I've been using minim to play a soundfile in my sketch on Windows 10.
Until yesterday it just worked fine, but today I came across the error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ddf/minim/Recordable
```

or sometime

```
ClassNotFoundException: ddf.minim.Minim
```

So I can't run the sketch.

Currently, the error shows up only on my windows10. But on my MacBook that works just as fine.
Does Anybody has ever come across this issue here?

My code:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;

Minim minim;
AudioSample audio;

void setup() {
minim = new Minim(this);
audio = minim.loadSample("greeting.wav", 2048);
}
void draw() {
}
void mousePressed() {
audio.trigger();
ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
```

Perhaps that line got accidentally deleted ?

(Off topic: try `CMD+T` to easily format the code: makes it easier to read/spot errors on the long run)

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to include the import ddf.minim.*; in my question... Actually I have that one In my code.

Comment: Interesting. Are you using the Processing IDE or a different IDE (e.g. eclipse, IntelliJ, NetBeans, etc.) ? Have you tried reinstalling the Minim library ?

Comment: I just researched around that and found out perhaps it's about clas path error. But I haven't ever worked on Java stuff so I have no idea how to fix it... Do you know useful information around that?

Comment: Did reinstalling the Minim library change anything ? (e.g. use Sketch > Import Library > Add Library > search for Minim to first remove then re-add the library)

Comment: I tried but still getting the error. By the way, I realized that I installed Processing itself on OneDrive. I assume that might be problematic. So I'm gonna try to reinstall to another location and see what will happen.